# Как пропустить часть кода

Tags: php

Есть ли способ "перепрыгнуть" часть php кода? Например:

PHP сервер проверяет, передал ли js ему значение `ulog`, если да - выполняет код дальше, если нет - пропускает часть кода и продолжает выполнять его.
Подробнее:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "testsite", "testsite", "LHVideo");
$login = $_POST['ulog'];
//эту часть он пропускает, если ulog не передано
    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT password FROM accounts WHERE login='$login'");
    $array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if(empty($array['password'])){
        echo("true");
    }else{
        echo("false");
    }
//с этого места продолжает выполнять код
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.if.php http://php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого существует условный оператор `if`

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "testsite", "testsite", "LHVideo");
if (isset($_POST['ulog']) {
    //эту часть он пропускает, если ulog не передано
    $login = $_POST['ulog'];
    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT password FROM accounts WHERE login='$login'");
    $array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if(empty($array['password'])){
        echo("true");
    }else{
        echo("false");
    }
}
//с этого места продолжает выполнять код
```

Comment: Т.к. isset() может пропускать строки нулевой длины: `$str = '';

var_dump( isset($str) ); // true` , то лучше было бы использовать `if (!empty($_POST['ulog'])`

Comment: @Эдуард `isset` делает именно то, что требуется - существует ли значение в массиве, т.е. біло ли оно передано от пользователя. Кроме того `!empty()` пропустит также если передали `0` или `'false'`. Если нужно проверить на непустоту, то нужно писать так `if (isset($_POST['ulog']) && $_POST['ulog'] === '')`. `trim()` добавить по вкусу

Comment: ошибаетесь, уважаемый: `$str = 0; var_dump( !empty($str) ); // false` то же касается и передачи false: `$str = false;

var_dump( !empty($str) ); // false`

Comment: @Эдуард Еще раз перечитайте свой последний комментарий и обратите внимание, что вы пишете **!** empty(). С таким же успехом будет `$str = ''; var_dump( !empty($str) ); // false`

Comment: @Эдуард Который также пропустит `0` и `false`

Comment: @Эдуард [Изучайте](https://ideone.com/2ToK0H)

Comment: @ AntonShchyrov вот вам __[наглядный пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/216fd1e573eead8c03b4f7815cf22438a958e6d3)__

Comment: @Эдуард Еще раз, посмотрите мою ссылку. Запустите мой код. Подумайте. Не нужно кидаться статическим кодом. Это я все видел. Вы сейчас по своей невнимательности, неправы.

Comment: я не хочу с вами спорить, но очевидных вещей вы принципиально не хотите замечать. Это ваше право, тема закрыта.

Comment: @Эдуард Скажите, если `!empty(0) == false` выполнится ли условие `if ( !empty(0) ) {..}`?